# Can't upload picture to localhost php - permission denied

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

So, I'm trying to upload pictures(book cover images, specifically) using a PHP script, but I'm getting a "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error. I'm just doing it through my Ubuntu VM, so I should be able to change any permissions necessary.

Here's my php code:

```
if (!empty($cover))
        {
            if ((($cover_type == 'image/gif') || ($cover_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($cover_type == 'image/pjpeg') ||
              ($cover_type == 'image/png')) && ($cover_size > 0) && ($cover_size <= MAXFILESIZE) &&
              ($cover_width <= MAXIMGWIDTH) && ($cover_height <= MAXIMGHEIGHT))
            {
                if ($_FILES['cover']['error'] == 0)
                {
                      // Move the file to the target upload folder
                      $target = UPLOADPATH . basename($cover);
                      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'], $target))
                      {
                      }
```

UPLOADPATH = images/

My php.ini file:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/html/my_site/tmp_file_upload/
```

My apache2.conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/my_site/tmp_file_upload/
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/my_site/images/>
     Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

I own the tmp_file_upload directory and the images directory, and I have write permissions on both. There are several other similar questions on this site, and that's how I knew to look in the php.ini file and the apache2.conf file, but nothing really answers why it's still not allowing me to add the image.

Comment: It's not you that should be owning the directory. The apache user should be the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ownership of the folder so that Apache may write to it

In your terminal type

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/my_site/tmp_file_upload/
```

where www-data is the normal user and group of apache

Comment: To prevent simular problems (and questions here on SO by this user), I'd suggest doing a recursive chown on `/var/www/html/`

Comment: good point @icecub, this would be done with the -hR flags: `sudo chown -hR www-data:www-data /var/www/html/`

Comment: Thank you! That worked, though I couldn't change the entire html directory, or I wouldn't be able to save the file I was working on.